# How to allow a Lambda that is inside a private VPC to make a GET request to a Regional API in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

I have a lambda that needs to be inside a private subnet in the VPC so that it can connect to a Neptune database, but by doing it I can't make a GET request from a Regional API from my API gateway, from the research I made it seems like I need to set a NAT Gateway to connect to a public subnet in order to be able to make the GET request that I need to do.

I'm asking this question to make sure that what I need to do is set up a NAT Gateway, [and if so what would be the best way to do that, is this a good guide on how to do it?](https://www.datanextsolutions.com/blog/using-nat-gateways-in-aws/)

If setting up a NAT Gateway isn't the best way to resolve my issues, what would be?

I tried changing to a public subnet, but soing that made it so that I couldn't connect to the Neptune database

Comment: NAT Gateway is one straightforward way to do it.  Another, depending on the regional API you're calling, might be Private Link.  Of the two, Nat Gateway covers all internet access , which can be an egress concern, but Private Link can only connect to one API, so it scales poorly.

Comment: Read [Introducing Amazon API Gateway Private Endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/).